# Browse through tags for photos in Plex

Tags: photos, plex

Plex has a [feature that automatically tags photos](https://support.plex.tv/articles/234976627-auto-tagging-of-photos/). It's easy to find photos in a certain tag by typing (the first characters of) the tag in the search field. To do that, you obviously need to know the name of the tag.

Is it possible to just browse a list of tags, maybe sorted by the number of pictures tagged as such?